# Names of copied files from USB device to HDD have all become uppercase. How to fix it?

Tags: filenames, openbsd, removable-storage, fat32

I am currently using OpenBSD 5.5-release.

Whenever I copy files or directories from my USB device to the local HDD, the names of the copied files have all become uppercase.

What causes it?

How do I fix it?

Comment: What is the FS of the USB?

Comment: The cause is probably the file-system of the usb.

Comment: @Karlo Filesystem is FAT32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it (each time it happens) with this command:

> `find local_directory_name -depth -exec sh -c 'dir="$(dirname "$0")"; FILE="$(basename "$0")"; lowfile="$(echo "$FILE" | tr "A-Z" "a-z")"; if [ "$lowfile" != "$FILE" ]; then mv "$0" "$dir/$lowfile"; fi' {} ";"`

Type this all as one line (replacing `local_directory_name`
with the name of the directory to which you copied the files). 
You can break it into multiple lines by inserting backslashes. 
Or you can put the part after `sh -c` into a script file.

This enumerates all the files in the directory (including subdirectories, recursively)
and executes the given commands on each one. 
`-depth` makes it work "bottom-up", so it processes all the entries in a directory
before it processes (renames) the directory itself. 
Each filename (relative path starting from *local_directory_name*) is broken down
into a directory portion and a plain filename (just the bottom component). 
Then the filename is converted from upper case to lower case. 
If this is different from the existing filename,
it renames the file to the lower-case name. 
I added this check to prevent the diagnostic messages you would otherwise get
from trying to rename a file to itself, which would happen if you had a file
whose name contained no letters (i.e., was numerals and special characters only). 
Or, for that matter, if you had a file whose name contained no *capital* letters.

Afterthought:
another way to avoid `mv 123 123` errors is to add `-name "*[A-Z]*"` after `-depth`,
which tells `find` to process only names that contain at least one capital letter.

Comment: See also [Rename file names from lower case to upper case](http://superuser.com/q/129917/354511) on Super User – although none of the answers there are recursive.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned you are using the FAT32 file system. FAT, as well as NTFS are case insensitive FSes. I am assuming the driver does uppercase only to make sure there is not >1 file in the dir with the same name (though with different casing).

The problem you describe has been around for a while. See [this thread](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1072531) from 2008 for example.

I suggest using a different FS or using TAR archives on your FAT/NFTS drives to retain casing.

Comment: Which FS is acceptable to both OpenBSD and Microsoft Windows?

Comment: `I suggest using a different FS` I can't because I do have to copy files from Microsoft Windows OS platform from time to time.

Comment: Then it might be an idea to save tar-archives to your FAT/NTFS drive. Tar-archives save all file info correctly.