# why can I not rename directories on my walkman?

Tags: linux, files, mv, vfat

```bsh
$ lsblk -o+FSTYPE /dev/sdc1
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT     FSTYPE
sdc1   8:33   1  3.7G  0 part /mnt/bart_sdc1 vfat
$ cd /mnt/bart_sdc1
$ file dvorak-walzes
dvorak-walzes: directory
$ ls -dl dvorak-walzes
drwxrwxr-x 2 bart wheel 16384 Oct 23 14:03 dvorak-walzes
$ ls -dl .
drwxrwxr-x 13 bart wheel 32768 Jan  1  1970 .
$ mv /mnt/bart_sdc1/{d,D}vorak-walzes
mv: cannot move '/mnt/bart_sdc1/dvorak-walzes' to a subdirectory of itself,
'/mnt/bart_sdc1/Dvorak-walzes/dvorak-walzes'
$ type mv
mv is /usr/bin/mv
$ uname -rsv
Linux 5.3.7-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 18 00:17:03 UTC 2019
```

Comment: please, expand *mv* command

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149222/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller, that may be correct, weird I never noticed before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (driver for the) FAT filesystem is case *insensitive*, meaning `dvorak-walzes` is equivalent to `Dvorak-walzes`, which is why you get the complaint from `mv` that:

> mv: cannot move '/mnt/bart_sdc1/dvorak-walzes' to a subdirectory of itself

A portion of the [Linux Kernel VFAT documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfat.txt) says:

> ```
> check=s|r|n   -- Case sensitivity checking setting.
>                  s: strict, case sensitive
>                  r: relaxed, case insensitive
>                  n: normal, default setting, currently case insensitive
> ```

Comment: thanks, and sorry for the duplicate. I did not assume case sensitivity problems because the case is retained in files on the FAT filesystem after copying files onto it or after remounting.